# Converting YUV to YUV420 Android onPreview

Tags: android, image-processing, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

a)I was wondering what is the difference between YUV and YUV420? b)I want to use the raw frames from Camera and convert them into YUV420 in real time. What is the fastest way to do this? I used bitmap factory to convert from yuv to jpg and I used onDraw() method to draw the bitmap. However, this takes some time to process. What is the best alternative to do the conversion if I want converting from YUV to YUV420?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV explains YUV and some of the different color formats.  It also has code for converting between some color formats. If you want to operate on 30fps camera input in real time, you should probably let GLES do the work for you, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg

Comment: I was wondering to know if YUV420 is same as NV21? If not do you know where can I find the algorithm to convert from NV21 to YUV420?

Comment: http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php describes (in varying levels of detail) various color formats, notably YV12 and NV21 (supported by the camera) and NV12 and I420 (supported by MediaCodec).  All of the formats are YUV (as opposed to RGB, XYZ, etc.)

Comment: I want to do some image rendering with openGL (from YV raw frame to rgb) and draw it on my on the surface. I know that in Java you can use bitmap and canvas to draw bitmap on a surfaceview. I want to do the similar thing but using opengl. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: See https://github.com/google/grafika, which does a number of things with camera input and OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very straight forward way to convert from NV12 to YV12/YUV 420. Two lines of code did the job for me:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        try {
            // set view of surface in cameraview
            Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

            p.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);

            mCamera.setParameters(p);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            }
```

}