# Android Camera Frame Rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-camera, surfaceview

I am trying to render my camera frames in Android and make use of canvas,bitmap,onDraw() to display the frames on my Surfaceview. However my code performance which does the rendering on the Native side is taking up to 70% of my cpu. The rendering speed is good but CPU consumption is bad.The problem is that I have another overlaying surfaceview(surfaceview2) to display something else while I am rendering and capturing camera. I was wondering how may I reduce the cpu consumption and make use of gpu more or etc. The possible solutions so far are :
a) using opengl to draw my frames on surfaceview but limited resources and sample codes
b) using native side to draw my frames but limited resources as well

Does anyone know how can I perform  YV12 to rbg using above techniques?

Comment: Is this the same project as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706700/ ? What are you trying to do?  It seemed like you were sending it directly to a SurfaceView or TextureView from the answer there; what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Fadden, I have Surfaceview1 that is displaying something and Surfaceview2(overlaid surface) that is doing camera capturing. I want to grab the frames from my camera and render them. I used native code which the performance was good but my cpu percentage went up. I am looking for a solution to lower the cpu usage. I couldn't find anything specific to this on Opengl. Do you think the openGl is the solution. Isn't opengl using native?

Comment: "OpenGL ES" and "native" are not synonymous. As noted in the answer by Isogen74, the camera data can be treated as an "external" texture. This is used in a few activities in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), such as "texture from camera". Grafika does not employ any native (NDK) code in the app itself.

Comment: I am not able to deploy Grafika on my Device...

Comment: I found this one but I am not sure how to use an overlay surface on top of the GlSurfaceview

Comment: Create a SurfaceView, use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean) to put it above the GLSurfaceView. See "multi-surface test" in Grafika for an example.

Comment: I found this link: http://www.roman10.net/effective-color-conversion-yuv-rgb-in-android-in-assembly/comment-page-1/#comment-6452 that does the conversion in Assembly level. However it only applies on one picture. Can you show me how can I apply this on my camera bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the modern GPUs can decode YUV natively; the issue is how to get the YUV surface into OpenGL ES as this is not normally something which Open GL ES does ...

Most operating systems (Android included) let you import external surfaces into OpenGL ES via the EGL_image_external extension, and these external surfaces can be marked up a being YUV.

The only problem is that I'm not entirely sure how this works on the Android side (sorry) - so someone else will have to answer that. I only know the graphics driver side - just know that it is possible on most modern mobile GPUs.

Comment: If you're curious, the Android mechanism is "SurfaceTexture". The system is described here: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html