# Converting YUV (yCbCr420p) to RGB in GLSL fragment shader?

Tags: java, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I understand the same question has appeared quite a lot, I have tried every single solution I could find and nothing is working.

I am receiving 3 buffers (each for Y, Cr, Cb) per frame. I am currently just binding them to a red channel. The Y buffer is 1 byte/pixel and the Cr and Cb buffers are 1/4 size, so it ties in nicely with the examples I see using width/2 and height/2 for the U and V texture maps, as follows;

```
int glFormat = GL20.GL_RED;
int glType = GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
int glInternalFormat = GL20.GL_RED;

GL20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GL20.glBindTexture(glTarget, yTexHandle);
GL20.glTexImage2D(glTarget, 0, glInternalFormat, width, height, 0, glFormat, glType, buffer);

int uvWidth = videoWidth/2;
int uvHeight = videoHeight/2;

GL20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0+2);
GL20.glBindTexture(glTarget, cbTexHandle);
GL20.glTexImage2D(glTarget, 0, glInternalFormat, uvWidth, uvHeigth, 0, glFormat, glType, cbBuffer);
GL20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0+1);
GL20.glBindTexture(glTarget, crTexHandle);
GL20.glTexImage2D(glTarget, 0, glInternalFormat, uvWidth, uvHeight, 0, glFormat, glType, crBuffer);
```

This is my frag shader;

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_texture_cr;
uniform sampler2D u_texture_cb;

void main() {
  float y = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).r;
  float u = texture2D(u_texture_cr, v_texCoords).r - 0.5;
  float v = texture2D(u_texture_cb, v_texCoords).r - 0.5;
  float r = y + 1.402 * v;
  float g = y - 0.344 * u - 0.714 * v;
  float b = y + 1.772 * u;
  gl_FragColor = v_color * vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);
}
```

While it might not be the best algorithm for conversion, I have tried every alternative I could find and it always looks roughly the same, very green and very pink.

I believe the issue to be the buffers themselves, or how they get bound to GL, rather than the frag shader itself. I have tried switching the u's and v's, and even trying u for everything and v for everything and the result is always the same, so it seems that by the time the u and v buffers get to the shader they are not right.

I have printed out segments of the Cb and Cr buffer to get a feel for what their values are, here's an example;

```
Cr: -124 Cb: 110
Cr: -126 Cb: 109
Cr: -127 Cb: 107
Cr: -128 Cb: 106
Cr: 127 Cb: 104
Cr: 127 Cb: 101
Cr: 127 Cb: 99
```

Note this is a Java ByteBuffer. I have tried using glType as GL_BYTE instead of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and it just looks a lot worse. I have also tried using the alpha channel with GL_ALPHA or GL_LUMINANCE as the format, GL_LUMINANCE looks slightly different but still roughly the same output.

Screenshot from 2 different videos;[image]

Also, the package which I get these frames from has the ability to convert to RGBA frames, this works perfectly, however it is an expensive process (~30ms compared to ~2ms). It is also a native method and I can't find the source for it, so I don't know what it's doing in the background, but I guess it is proof that when I get the buffers they are correct.

**UPDATE**

I have tried to implement gamma and saturation in the shader as suggested by MoDJ, using [this (BT709 conversions)](https://github.com/mdejong/MetalBT709Decoder/blob/master/Renderer/BT709.h) from that answer. The output is still pretty much the same though. The shader resulted in this;

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_texture_cr;
uniform sampler2D u_texture_cb;

const float yScale = 255.0 / (235.0 - 16.0); //(BT709_YMax-BT709_YMin)
const float uvScale = 255.0 / (240.0 - 16.0); //(BT709_UVMax-BT709_UVMin)

float BT709_nonLinearNormToLinear(float normV) {
    if (normV < 0.081) {
        normV *= (1.0 / 4.5);
    } else {
        float a = 0.099;
        float gamma = 1.0 / 0.45;
        normV = (normV + a) * (1.0 / (1.0 + a));
        normV = pow(normV, gamma);
    }
    return normV;
}

void main() {
    float y = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).r;
    float u = texture2D(u_texture_cr, v_texCoords).r - 0.5;
    float v = texture2D(u_texture_cb, v_texCoords).r - 0.5;

    y = y - 16.0/255.0;

    float r = y*yScale +                          v*uvScale*1.5748;
    float g = y*yScale - u*uvScale*1.8556*0.101 - v*uvScale*1.5748*0.2973;
    float b = y*yScale + u*uvScale*1.8556;

    r = clamp(r, 0.0, 1.0);
    g = clamp(g, 0.0, 1.0);
    b = clamp(b, 0.0, 1.0);

    r = BT709_nonLinearNormToLinear(r);
    g = BT709_nonLinearNormToLinear(g);
    b = BT709_nonLinearNormToLinear(b);
```

Comment: You cannot just interpret signed integer data as an UNORM format.

Comment: sorry not sure I follow?

Comment: You have number of issues, non-linear sampling, not handling gamma, it does not look like you are doing a saturate on the output RGB values. I would suggest that you start with a fully working example and adapt that logic to your OpenGL code, see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911662/does-h-264-encoded-video-with-bt-709-matrix-include-any-gamma-adjustment

Comment: The buffer contains signed integers, which is not what I would expect. I think the buffers should use `unsigned char`, as values for video typically range from 0-255 and sometimes from 16-240. If the buffer is correct, then you're implicitly converting to signed integers when printing the values.

Comment: See also: http://www.darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html

Comment: Finally: try removing `v_color *` from the shader code. It is likely you're not initializing it to `vec3( 1.0 )`.

Comment: That's for the answers folks. @MoDJ I have tried to implement gamma and saturation, please see updated question with the shader.

Comment: @PaulHoux I don't deal with byte's a lot, but from what I read this is just how Java deals with bytes - "The conversion of an integer value from 128 up to 255 to a byte results in what Java views as a negative number." - so I don't believe the actual values are negative, it's just how it outputs when printing it.

Comment: A test case that makes use of Apple BT.709 gamma (1.96 with slope) can be found at this url https://github.com/mdejong/MetalBT709Decoder/blob/master/Renderer/osxcolor_test_image_24bit_BT709.m4v?raw=true, note that you should be using the Apple specific gamma slope as opposed to the generic BT.709 one you grabbed from the example project. (Use Apple196_nonLinearNormToLinear not BT709_nonLinearNormToLinear).

Comment: The reason you want to use the Apple specific curve is because it converts to linear light while the BT.709 gamma function does not. More details on that horror show can be found here with an example: https://github.com/mdejong/MetalBT709Decoder/issues/1

Comment: Also, you want to subtract 128.0/255.0 from Cb and Cr to center them, 0.5 is not exactly the right floating point value.

Comment: Thanks @MoDJ, as mentioned in my answer below, the problem was actually incorrectly binding the textures and it wasn't receiving any UV data what so ever. I'll have a play with optimizing the gamma as you suggested as the colours do still look a tad off, but for now I'm super happy it just works as it is.

Comment: If it's possible to get these as native YUV buffers from Android's media stack, you might want to import them directly if you can (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863741/android-camera-frame-rendering). This is often zero copy and color conversion will be done automatically as part of the external sampler access.

Comment: Thanks @solidpixel however this is not Android, just plain Desktop. I have been wondering about using external textures though as supposedly a faster solution than glTexImage2D, but I can't find much on the subject. Anyway, now that I finally got it working I have already optimized it down to a single texture and using the rgb channels to map yuv instead. It might be nice to avoid glTexImage2D, but it seems to take only a few ms to do the task anyway so it might just be premature optimization.

Comment: The color test image will show any remaining problems in your implementation. Your gamma curve is not quite right and you will actually need to do 2 render passes to get scaling working properly (linear sampling the non-linear YCbCr textures leads to distorted color when scaling up to match the view dimensions). The output should be within +-2 for each RGB value otherwise your shader logic is not quite correct. It can be very difficult to notice a math issue from looking at regular images.

Comment: Thanks @MoDJ, I have done a side by side comparison of a few videos (one using YUV shader and another forcing native frame conversion to RGB) and they look absolutely identical to my (untrained) eye, so while it might not be absolute precision I am happy with the results. Performance is much more important than accuracy for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just solved this, silly error on my part when setting the shader uniforms!

This is what I was doing;

```
GL20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0+2);
GL20.glBindTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, cbTexHandle);
program.setUniformi("u_texture_cb", GL20.GL_TEXTURE0+2);

GL20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0+1);
GL20.glBindTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, crTexHandle);
program.setUniformi("u_texture_cr", GL20.GL_TEXTURE0+1);
```

It should actually be;

```
program.setUniformi("u_texture_cb", 2);
program.setUniformi("u_texture_cr", 1);
```

So if you end up getting a green and pink display from a YUV shader, I believe it's just down to not actually getting any UV values (they are probably just all zeros)